# Is there a possibility to easily add a col-xl-*?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add further col-* classes. 
I want to add col-xl-* but it's very time consuming adding every class manually.

If i use http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ I just can edit the lg but i will loose a screen width so I want to add another one. Is there a easy way to do that?

Regards

Comment: There's no automated way if that's what you're asking. And what would xl cover (lg covers ≥1200px)?

Comment: Yes, I want that the xl container has a width of 1400px

Comment: I have added it manually but I'm just interested if it's possible to automate it in any way.

Comment: Depending on what IDE you are using you could create a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way to do it is use the .LESS source files. Besides that no.

The files you should look at are: grid.less, variables.less and mixins.less. I wouldn't edit those actual files though, because of updates to Bootstrap. I would start your own custom.less file and then @import that into the bootstrap.less file. That way it will generate your CSS with the rest of the bootstrap CSS.

This article on SmashingMagazine is an excellent example and where I got the idea from: [Customizing Bootstrap](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/12/customizing-bootstrap/)

For some reason though, the article is currently not there or broken. I reported this to them, so hopefully it comes back soon.